# Convert int to unsigned short java

Tags: java, int, unsigned, short

I have written a .obj parser in java to modelize 3D objects on iPhone. I would like to export the data as a binary file, which must be as small as possible. I have plenty of indices that would fit a unsigned short, but they are represented as int in java.

I would like to use the ByteBuffer class to do the conversion just before writing the data in a file. I suppose I will have to manipulate bytes before pushing them into the ByteBuffer but I have no idea how to do so.

Thank you in advance if you can help me.

Comment: There is no such thing as an unsigned anything in java...

Comment: Why not just cast to char ? This results in 16 bits

Comment: @Andrew White yes I know that, I wouldn't ask if I didn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Java, an unsigned short can be represented as a `char`. Just cast the int to char and use `putChar()` on the ByteBuffer.

```
myBuffer.putChar((char) my16BitInt);
```

Comment: +1: This does the same as `myBuffer.putShort((short) my16BitInt);`

Answer (score 4):

```
short toUint16(int i)
{
    return (short) i;
}

int toUint32(short s)
{
    return s & 0xFFFF;
}
```

Comment: `return s & 0xFFFF;`

Answer (score 2):

You can extract single bytes from your integers with

```
int i;
byte b1 = i & 0xFF;
byte b2 = (i >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html

```
dos.writeShort(value & 0xFFFF);
```